# django multiple objects update

Tags: django, forms, object

I have a model I want to update multiple objects field 'value' with the same 'substage' field value. At the moment I know how to update one object field 'value' with UpdateView but I do not know how to do it for multiple objects which has the same 'substage' number. Should I use a form ?

```
class ZoneSubStage(models.Model):
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

This is what I do at the moment:

```
class ZoneSubStageUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ZoneSubStage
    fields = ['value']
    template_name = 'autostages/zonesubstage_update.html'
```

zonesubstage_update.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: What you are after is a [`FormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your model:

```
class ZoneSubStage(models.Model):
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Super override the `form_valid` method to call the update on all related `substage` objects, using `substage_set` if you want to set them all to the same value.  You can use the Django ORM `update()` method:

```
class ZoneSubStageUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = ZoneSubStage
    fields = ['value']
    template_name = 'autostages/zonesubstage_update.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object.substage_set.update(myfield='new-value')
        return super(ZoneSubStageUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I do not want to set them all to the same value. I want to be able to decide what value to set for each of them separately within one form. So, imagine one page with these values displayed so I can click on each of them separately and change value by typing it in and updating once one button update pressed for all of them.

Comment: @BlueTomato then you need to use a `Django FormSet` as @ivan mentioned.